# Scala: Return type of abstract method

Tags: scala

I cannot figure out how to specify the return type of a method an abstract class A, if the same method of the concrete classes have different return (sub)types:

```
abstract class A {
    def method: List[Common (?)]   // I want to force all subclasses to define this method
}

class B1 extends A {
    def method(a,b,c): List[Sub1] = {...}
}

class B2 extends A {
    def method(a,b,c): List[Sub2] = {...}
}
```

I tried to define a common trait of `Sub1` and `Sub2`:

```
abstract class Common   // or abstract class
case class Sub1 extends Common
case class Sub2 extends Common
```

but I keep getting this:

```
Compilation error[class B1 needs to be abstract, 
since method "method" in class A of type => List[Common] is not defined]
```

If I don't define the return type in class A, I get the same error with `... type => Unit ...` instead.

How can I solve that?

Comment: I see no Java in this question.

Comment: Ok I removed the tag. I thought it was an abstract question about inheritance.

Comment: No, it's quite specific to Scala's type system.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik No, it isn't. It's an inheritance problem.

Comment: @m-z It's either a fully abstract problem about general inheritance, or it is a specific problem about one language's type system. It is definitely not a problem specific to Scala and Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 def method: List[Common]
```

Is not the same as

```
 // returns `List[Common]` to simplify things, but it would be the same if we returned a sub-type
 def method(a: ?, b: ?, c: ?): List[Common] = {...}
```

The first is a parameterless method that returns a `List[Common]`, and the second is a method with *three* parameters that returns a `List[Common]`. The compiler sees these as two completely different methods. The fact that they have the same name means nothing.

The compiler is complaining because `def method: List[Common]` is not defined in the subclasses of `A`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles:

```
  abstract class Common   // or abstract class
  case class Sub1() extends Common
  case class Sub2() extends Common

  abstract class A {
    def method(): List[Common]
  }

  class B1 extends A {
    def method(): List[Sub1] = ???
  }

  class B2 extends A {
    def method(): List[Sub2] = ???
  }
```

All I have done is:

- add the `()` to `Sub1()` and `Sub2()`
- return `List[Common]` from `A`

**EDIT**

As @m-z mentioned, it works because every `def method()` has the same signature now.